# Page load looks ugly before css comes in

Tags: css, load

How can I improve the page load on this page? http://designwebs.co.uk/griffiths/news-6/

Basically before the css gets loaded the page doesn't look very pretty.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: BTW: When I open your site I get this JavaScript error `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` :-)

Comment: Thank you, do you know what it means?

Comment: In your script `theme_scripts.js` on line **104** there is definied jQuery, and it don't know this jQuery...

Answer (score 2):

Some general tips:

1. Minimize your css.
2. Combine your css into one file (use a server side utlity).
3. Same with your javscripts.

And use a preloader. This will display a loading icon until your whole content has been loaded

http://niklausgerber.com/blog/preloadme-a-lightweight-jquery-website-preloader/

Answer (score 1):

When you have a big CSS-File, it takes a while to load it.

Try to use a clean CSS. Some tips are documentet [here](http://www.cleancss.com/)

A other option is to show the site until everything is loaded. [Here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/display-loading-graphic-until-page-fully-loaded/) you have an easy-to-understand code snip by CSS-Tricks

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip for the clean CSS, I haven't seen that tool before and found it compressed the css by 32% which is brilliant.

Comment: @LyndsayMoon I just saw that all of your questions are solved. So can you mark an acceptet answer in all of your question?